# How to roll back from a Git merge after multiple merges

Tags: git, merge, revert

Ok so i had this situation today where i merged a branch into master from another developer who had mistakingly merged his dev work into the branch along with the change he needed deployed.  I tried rolling back the merge after i had already pushed to remote (and then deployed that to some production servers - it was after a uat) but couldn't because i couldn't find a common or initial ancestor.

Heres the problem:

Dev creates a new branch based on master, and in the course of the working and testing cycles periodically merges master into the dev branch and then pushes the branch to remote tracking branch. This has been happening weekly for about 2 months.

In the meantime, other devs have been merging master into their branches and then merging the merged branch back into master for testing and deployment.  So this one devs branch is peppered with commits from his work as well as commits from all the other devs commits during the 2 months i.e. theres no clear ancestor for this particular branch.

It seems impossible to roll back just the changes from this branch since it has had master routinely merged into it over the course of months (for this branch, year or 2 for the project in all).  I tried the usual methods to revert the merge and commit etc. I can't reset as it has beeb pushed to origin.

Is there a way to undo the merge in this situation?

Comment: There is no easy answer to your question. You will have to identify the merges you don't want to be present and then revert those, or you will have to reset way back in history and then reapply merges from other developers. I think that whatever approach you go with is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The dev did a weekly push to remote (plus some) after merging master in. So could I have tried reverting each of those commits individually, and then though master was periodically merged in? (Does sound like a lot of work :D

Comment: As I said, you will have a lot of work regardless of the approach you choose. It might be better to set up a new, unsoiled, branch from some point in the history, and then ask the dev to cherrypick the commits he needs for the issue he's implementing. Ie. instead of trying to salvage the existing branch, try looking into what it would take to create a new one instead. It might even be less work than fixing the existing one to just reimplement some of those commits if they turn out to be hard to cherrypick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to rewrite history on master (exceptionally), and you don't have other merges into master yet, you might consider:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~
git push -f origin master
```

**CAUTION:** this rewrites `master` history, so all your dev's need to refresh (`git fetch`) and make sure they don't merge this old code back into master.

NOTE: You can replace HEAD~ with the commit reference just before the wrong merge. All commits starting the wrong merge commit will then be removed. Make sure to keep references (branches, ...) so you don't lose that work.

Comment: Unfortunately it has been pushed to remote and has been pulled by numerous entities so i can't rewrite the history.  I did `git reset --hard HEAD^` after a failed revert. Interestingly though if i checked out the commit several back i ended up with all the changes from the dev (plus a few more) and created a branch. But i couldn't merge that branch back into master or update master to point to the branch as it was already merged. Nearly got it!